# Retrieve Items With Flag Set

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

is it possible to retrieve only items with a certain flag status by using a SearchFilter?
For example, to retrieve all unread items, the search filter below is used:

```
SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));
```

Is there an equivalent way to retrieve all items that don't have a completed flag assigned?
Thanks

Comment: Could you tell a bit more about your intention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the pidTagFlagstatus extended property  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc842307.aspx eg if the value is 2 then is flagged if the value is 1 its complete eg

```
String MailboxToAccess = "user@domain.com";            
ExtendedPropertyDefinition PR_FLAG_STATUS = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x1090, MapiPropertyType.Integer);
ExtendedPropertyDefinition FlagRequest = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Common, 0x8530, MapiPropertyType.String);
SearchFilter sfSearchFilter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(PR_FLAG_STATUS, 2);
PropertySet fiFindItemPropset = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
fiFindItemPropset.Add(FlagRequest);
FolderId FolderToAccess = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, MailboxToAccess);
ItemView ivItemView = new ItemView(1000);
ivItemView.PropertySet = fiFindItemPropset;
FindItemsResults<Item> FindItemResults = null;
do
{
    FindItemResults = service.FindItems(FolderToAccess, sfSearchFilter, ivItemView);
    foreach (Item itItem in FindItemResults.Items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(itItem.Subject);
        Object FlagValue = null;
        if (itItem.TryGetProperty(FlagRequest, out FlagValue))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Flag : " + FlagValue);
        }
    }
    ivItemView.Offset += FindItemResults.Items.Count;
} while (FindItemResults.MoreAvailable);
```